# How to reverse point size in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please, help me with this point. I need the positive values to be represented as small points and negative as large points. If I tape minus before size, the point sizes are right but the legend is changing:

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=runif(20),z=rnorm(20))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(aes(size=-z))
```

so that does not suite.

Comment: try `last_plot() + scale_size(range = c(5,1)) + guides(size = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution would be to use `scale_size()` and set your own `breaks` and then `labels` in opposite direction. Changed range of `z` values to get better representation.

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=runif(20),z=(-13:6))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(aes(size=-z))+
  scale_size("New legend",breaks=c(-10,-5,0,5,10),labels=c(10,5,0,-5,-10))
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61920721/1870254 is a much better solution, that doesn't require you to fiddle with the aesthetics, legend title, breaks & labels.

Answer (score 8):

Little late, but an easier way would just to add `trans='reverse'` to scale_size.

Example:

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=runif(20),z=z=(-13:6))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
geom_point(aes(size=z)) +
scale_size(trans = 'reverse')
```

[image: example plot with reversed size scale]

Answer (score 3):

While this question is very old - and has an accepted answer - the comment from baptiste that suggests using `last_plot() + scale_size(range = c(5,1)) + guides(size = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` works very elegantly and simply. For my data where I needed to produce the same result as OP, this worked with zero modification required.